# Keras can not download anythings

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I am trying and testing the TF-2.0 for a few days. `Keras` or `tensorflow_datasets` can not download anythings even for example data or pre-train models. for example, I want to downlaod the pre-trained model of MobileNetV2.

```
# Create the base model from the pre-trained model MobileNet V2

base_model = tf.keras.applications.MobileNetV2(input_shape=IMG_SHAPE,
                                               include_top=False,
                                               weights='imagenet')
```

While I run the code, the program can not get the file from internet.

```
Downloading data from https://github.com/JonathanCMitchell/mobilenet_v2_keras/releases/download/v1.1/mobilenet_v2_weights_tf_dim_ordering_tf_kernels_1.0_160_no_top.h5
```

For the another resources such as image, I manually download the resource file from Colab and copy them into `~/tensorflow_datasets/cats_vs_dogs/2.0.1`. It's work.

My runtime environment:

- Ubuntu 19.04
- Python 3.7.3
- Tensorflow CPU only

Comment: Is the `h5py` package installed in the same python environment? It could be the .h5 file downloads, but then the code can't read it.

Comment: Are you getting any error messages? Or how are you determining it does not work?

Comment: h5py package was installed by Ubuntu.

Comment: When I run my code with any download operation of Tensorflow, the program will stop for a long time and no any massage.

Comment: I have resolved the problem by copy the model file *.h5 that was downloaded via browser into the default directory of Keras `~/.keras/models`.